# How to send array from classic asp to table in php page?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, asp-classic, parameter-passing

I am doing SQL query in ASP page, and getting a 100 rows and 7 columns of data.

For example, I read from the query string in my URL or the form I submitted as POST / GET,

I got this: " `myexample.com/order.php?month=2012-03` ", I use the " 2012-03 " as my value in ASP page to run a query " `SELECT * FROM CustomerSalesOrder WHERE date LIKE '2012-03%'` "

Now, as above mentioned, I got 100 rows with 7 columns of data about my customers purchase what in March.

How to convert these data into an array and passing to a PHP page to generate table with data display on the table ?

(I understand that I can run everything in 1 web programming language. But the step to run query in ASP page has been fixed, can not be changing; and the step to display data on PHP page also fixed. ASP page located in *myexample.com*, while PHP page located in *mywork.com*)

Please guide me the step-by-step of:

- dump my data into array in ASP page, and
- how to pass my data (in array form) to PHP page to display data in a proper formatted table form

I expect the expert to guides me the data converting into array in ASP, and the step of array passing to PHP page.

Then, in PHP page, how to explode every data in array or assign the data to value for variable? (I guess need to be using looping, any loop method is the best in this case?) Once I got the value either in looping or another way, then loop again into table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May i suggest that your asp page outputs the "Array" of SQL Data as XML, and the PHP page just reads the XML (Using CURL) and parses the XML into a php array?

Outputting SQL Data as XML:

```
''#### Build SQL Query to grab data as XML (you may want to put this in a stored procedure
dim SqlStr
SqlStr = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ( SELECT [ColA] AS 'A', [ColB] AS 'B', [ColC] AS 'C', [ColD] AS 'D', [ColE] AS 'E', [ColF] AS 'F', [ColG] AS 'G'" & _
         "                 FROM    CustomerSalesOrder " & _
         "                 WHERE [Date] LIKE '2012-03%' " & _
         "               FOR " & _
         "                 XML PATH('R') , " & _
         "                     ROOT('ROOT') " & _
         "               )) as XML"

set rs = db.execute(SqlStr)

do while not rs.eof
    XmlStr = rs("XML")
    rs.movenext
loop

''#### XML Headers
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
Response.Write XmlStr
```

The PHP page could read this as follows:

```
$URL = "URL to the ASP page";
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
$output = trim(curl_exec($ch));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output);

//#### Prep Array
var $TargetArray[];
$ArrayPointer = 0;

//#### Parse XML
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    $ColA = trim($child->A);
    $ColB = trim($child->B);
    $ColC = trim($child->C);
    $ColD = trim($child->D);
    $ColE = trim($child->E);
    $ColF = trim($child->F);
    $ColG = trim($child->G);

    //#### Push values into your array (This may be buggy, my php & multi dimensional arrays is a tad rusty)
    $row = array('ColA' => $ColA, 'ColB' => $ColB, 'ColC' => $ColC, 'ColD' => $ColD, 'ColE' => $ColE, 'ColF' => $ColF, 'ColG' => $ColG); 
    $TargetArray[$ArrayPointer] = $data;
    $ArrayPointer++;
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want to squirt the CURL XML into a HTML table, you could do this as follows:

```
//#### Parse XML from CURL into HTML Table
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "  <th>ColA</th>";
echo "  <th>ColB</th>";
echo "  <th>ColC</th>";
echo "  <th>ColD</th>";
echo "  <th>ColE</th>";
echo "  <th>ColF</th>";
echo "  <th>ColG</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($xml->children() as $child) { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->A) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->B) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->C) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->D) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->E) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->F) . "</th>";
    echo "  <th>" . trim($child->G) . "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I'm sure this will require some tweaking, but it should be enough to get you going with the both the PHP & ASP side of it.

Comment: For the ASP code you ought to ensure that the `Response.Codepage` is 65001.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this like that:

In your ASP page you could add a condition, if `json` parameter is present you display data from query as JSON (JSON code only, no html).

On PHP page display data from ASP page:

```
$aspData = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://myexample.com/order.php?month=2012-03&json=1'), true);
echo "<table>";
foreach($aspData as $row){
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $colName => $colVal){
    echo "<td>$colVal</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I don't know ASP but there should be function to convert array to JSON string.

Comment: http://www.aspjson.com/ will work, but there's nothing built-in to the language. JSON wasn't popular at the time, and Microsoft focussed all it seffort on XML.